# Is there a 2.83.6 LTS on Steam?

Tags: add-on

I went to install 2.83.6 via Steam but instead 2.90 got installed. Is there a mix up or something?

Comment: Where is the need to use Steam to install Blender? Should be a question, but a simple comment would do...

Comment: [All past versions of Blender](https://download.blender.org/release/) can be directly downloaded from Blender's website. I haven't used Blender on Steam, but I assume it only gives you the most recent version as it does with games.